# SQLAlchemy QueuePool Overflow Issue in FastAPI Application with Uvicorn

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, connection-pooling, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI application utilizing FastAPI, Uvicorn, SQLAlchemy, and MySQL. When I send numerous requests to the API, I encounter the error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 20 reached`

Configuration Details:
I've configured the database settings as follows:

```
engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Endpoint Database Access:
Database access within endpoints is managed using a dependency named get_db() as follows:

```
from database import SessionLocal

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal() 
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I expected the application to handle requests sequentially, given that I'm using only one worker thread in Uvicorn. However, despite this setup, I'm puzzled by the presence of more than one active connection in the pool concurrently. I've reviewed my configuration and usage patterns but haven't been able to pinpoint why this concurrency issue is occurring.

Comment: Is there a way for you to monitor currently active connections? Something like `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` in MySQL. I'm thinking that some of your requests might not close the connections they triggered, and eventually end up filling the pool.

Answer (score 0):

On the back of @FiddlingAway's comment. If your connection hits an error for example, you might not be closing your connection and they build up. You can use a context manager to better handle your database connection and ensure it's always closed after you've finished with it:

```
def get_db():
    with SessionLocal() as db: 
        try:
            yield db
        except Exception as err:
            # log your error
            # print(err) # for dev/testing
            db.rollback()
        finally:
            db.close()
```